# Setting all mocks to null in tearDown method & variables at class level in JUnit

Tags: optimization, junit, mocking

I have a two questions:

1.)  On tearDown method of mocks.
People says that its a common practice to set all the mocks to null in teardown method like below:

```
public void tearDown(){
   mockOne=null;
   mockTwo=null;
}
```

I want to know does this really make sense or we should be doing something useful in the tearDown?
JVM will not take care to nullify the mocks?

2. ) Also, whether all the variables that are being used in the jUnit should be defined at class level or at method level? I know creating at class level promotes code reuse but will it not uncessarary occupy memory all the time in maintaining the state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

I don't think your `tearDown` does a whole lot of useful things. Your test cases will usually be running on a different `VM` from the production server `VM`s, so there's no need to be so cautious about `GC` (if that's what the intention of setting the mocks to `null` is). The mock objects among the stubs that your test classes create will be eligible for `GC` as soon as they go out of scope, which is at worst, after execution of all the test cases and exiting of the `JVM`.

Sure it *might* help the `garbage-collector` reclaim these resources sooner than without it, but unless you run a really large suite of unit tests, this can't be a problem.

If, on the other hand, the idea is to make sure the changes made to the mock objects by one test method do not affect another subsequent test method, this makes sense somewhat.

Don't overthink these `fixtures` - have something to setup for the subsequent test case(s)? Do it in the `@Before` annotated `setUp` method. Have something like cleaning up resources like the database connections and system resources? Do it in the `After` annotated `tearDown` method.

Normally, you'll not even write a `tearDown` method unless you're faced with one of the above said requirements unlike the `setUp` method which might prove far more useful to you.

**2.**

My first point above partly answers your questions related to the memory footprint. There's no need to be so cautious with the unit tests.

You'd typically not write unit tests that are long running processes.

Besides, creating the objects closer to where you use them and limiting their scope and exposure to a required minimum is generally a good practice - so if you are not planning to reuse the objects/mocks, feel free to create them (and thereby make them go out of scope as soon as the test method completes the execution) in your test methods.

Answer (score 1):

To your first point, I would say that I personally seldom if ever have a use for a tearDown() method, certainly not to lose a reference to a mock object. I am not inclined to believe "people" on that one.

To your second point, just declare your variables in the smallest scope that you possibly can as what is paramount is that your tests both capture some required behavior and are easily comprehended.

As per usual, keep it simple and strive to have very minimal setup (Arrange), invocation of test subject (Act) and verification (Assert) in each test. If you have trouble with this, it's a sign that your test subject (or class under test) may be doing too much.